# ROLAP columnar Database

Tags: database, olap, rolap

We have a very simple use-case but we are having a hard time choosing the best DB solution that fits our needs.

The requirement:

An OLAP DB that allows us to query millions of records by different properties(thousands), and can hold one primary key. Also it must be partially fast when uploading the data.

The use-case:

We have a users database, and every user belongs to different properties. There are up to 10k properties, however most of users have less than 30 properties each.

Example table:

**user/properties**

user1/1,5,10

user2/7,5,9,24,42,1090

user3/9

user4/98,1049,2000

.
.

The ideal scenario is to have a columnar store database in which every property is a column, and the database allows more than 10k properties.

Monetdb fits us just right, but there are two very critical downsides:

- Bulk load is very low, in our tests it gave us 5ms per record uploaded. To upload 1M records it would take more than an hour, which is very slow.
- Bulk load fails on duplicate primary key (we would like to update the property values on that "on duplicate key", but it's not possible with this database).

We were thinking about druid also, but it's more "event" driven. You need a timestamp for when every property has been added. It has not been ruled out, however it's not the perfect fit for what we need.

I can give more explanation if needed, any guidance will be really appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how you bulk load into the database. A simple COPY INTO over a table of 100 columns and 125M rows doesn't take more then roughly a half hour on an ordinary 4core desktop and 16G RAM. See e.g. http://homepages.cwi.nl/~mk/ontimeReport

Beware that introducing 10K columns induces that all values are set, for each user. You might reconsider your database design and rely more on the user:property table setup.

Comment: Thanks mkersten. No this doesn't answer my question. I need 10k columns because of performance. This is an OLAP db to fast query properties, normal user:property table setup does not help me with what I need. Thanks anyway